# Jest with webpack provide plugin

Tags: reactjs, import, webpack, jestjs, es6-modules

I am using webpack-provide-plugin to import react.

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        "React": "react",
}),
```

// text.jsx

```
let text = (props) => (
  <div> 
    <p class="text">this.props.text</p>
  </div>
)

export default text
```

//text.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import text from 'text';

it('Renders text', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<text/>);
    expect(wrapper.hasClass("text")).toEqual(true);
});
```

But while running react component tests with jest, I get the error

```
ReferenceError: React is not defined
```

Ofcourse, because react is not imported explicitly. Is there a way to this problem other than explicit imports and giving up on provide-plugin ?

Comment: Didn't find a way through it. But in hindsight I thought it is better to remove the webpack providePlugin config. As importing should be better left to code then to build/bundling config.

Comment: Same issue here, I think it's important though

Comment: Does mocking help? I removed the providePlugin so got rid of this issue

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can create a setup file for Jest like this:

```
//jest.setup.js
window.React = require('react');
```

and add it to Jest config:
`"setupFiles": [ "<rootDir>/jest.setup.js" ]`,
http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#setupfiles-array

Comment: Just a note that this works for `DefinePlugin` as well.

Answer (score 0):

remove this line as you are proving this variable using webpack provide plugin;

import React from "react";